Minimizing the Spectral Norm of the Hadamard Product of a Quadratic Form Using CVX
I am trying to use CVX to minimize the spectral norm of the Hadamard product of two matrices, one of which is in quadratic form. Specifically, I am trying to minimize $\|{\bf A} \odot {\bf XX}^H\|_2$, where $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the spectral norm, and $\odot$ represents the Hadamard product operator. ${\bf A}$ is a positive definite matrix (independent of ${\bf X}$), so the function is convex in ${\bf X}$. The problem can be alternatively written as
$$
\begin{align}
\underset{t,{\bf X}}{\text{minimize}} \qquad&t\\
\text{subject to}  \qquad& {\bf A} \odot {\bf XX}^H \preceq t{\bf I}
\end{align}
$$
The problem written in this form is not accepted in CVX, because a quadratic form is used in the matrix inequality. Any idea how I can write this problem in a form that CVX accepts? Thank you so much for helping!

Are there missing constraints? As written, the optimal value is 0, attained when X = 0.

In my problem, there are other constraints, and there are other terms in the objective function. I'm showing only this term since it does not easily translate to CVX. Any idea how to translate such a spectral norm to CVX? Thanks for helping!
